# Remove blurriness on transform animations?

Tags: css, transform, css-animations

Its mid 2016, is there a good workaround to remove blurriness on transform animations?

Assume I have some div with text inside and I want to animate it with:

```
div:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 1s transform;
}
```

Honestly I tried all solutions that I could not find anything online. Most of solutions are a few years old.

One thing I tried that really makes things considerably cleaner is scaling the font up like crazy and then using transform scaling to bring it back to its original size. Now when the browser rasterizes my text when the animation runs it does so with a high quality image.

Is there any better way that is not so hacky?

**Clearer question**: How do I make animations of objects clear without my objects becoming blurry? There must be a way of deactivating the optimizations the browser is making.

I currently experience this using chrome / webkit browsers.

Comment: 1. Can you show an example on Codepen/JSFiddle? 2. What browser?

Comment: @makshh yes ofcourse.

Comment: @makshh https://jsfiddle.net/rtt0bp1w/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common question - the blurriness is caused by the way Chrome renders it's content, when not using hardware acceleration.

There's a commonly used soluton for  this (a hack, so to speak), 
that forces *webkit* to use the acceleration, making the elements not blurry anymore.

Take a look here:  [I've updated your jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtt0bp1w/2/)

You want to use the *translateZ*  or *translate3d* properties, when doing a transition, like so:

```
.one:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
  transition: 1s all;
}
.two:hover{
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateZ(0);
  transition: 1s all;
}
.three:hover{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 1s all;  
}
```